# Don't echo string if before string is similar to current string

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I don't want to echo string if before string is similar to current string. Let's say our strings are,

```
$strings = array("software","software","game","antivirus");
```

My difference function,

```
function ($val1,$val2) {
similar_text($val1,$val2,$percent);
if ($percent>83) {
// should not echo. But don't know how to do.
}
}
```

But I don't know how can I do it. I guess it should be with using for each.

Comment: Where does `$percent` and `similar_text()` come from? But if you don't want to echo above 83% then simply change it to `$percent<=83`

Comment: @lethalMango $percent is automatically generated by php's similar_text() function. Before rating topics, please make sure revise your scholar about the situation.

Comment: So I asked a question to understand your problem for my reference more. If I had known the answer I'd have answered myself. Before assuming I had rated topics, ensure you know who rates them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$strings = array("software","software","game","antivirus");

$lastString = '';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    similar_text($lastString, $string, $percent);
    if ($percent < 83) {
        echo "$string<br />";
        $lastString = $string;
    }
}
```

If you don't understand some part of it, leave a comment and I will clarify.

**Edit:**
I moved the `$lastString = $string;` inside the condition.

Consider the following list of strings:
`$strings = array("software","sofware","sofwart","ofwart","fwart","wart","warts");`

Leaving the `$lastString` assignment outside of the loop would only print `software` even though lots of the words are very very different `software` they are not so different from the previous word.

Moving it inside actually gives the output :

> software
>   sofwart
>   wart

Comment: Yeah, actually these strings were just an example. I will use this on sentences.

Answer (score 1):

```
$strings = array("software","software","game","antivirus");
$previous = '';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  if ($string===$previous) {
    continue;
  } else {
    echo $string;
    $previous = $string;
  }
}
```

But I think it's better to do it with for like this (it should be faster):

```
$strings = array("software","software","game","antivirus");
$num = count($strings);
for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
  if ($strings[$i]===$strings[$i-1] && $i!==0) {
    continue;
  } else {
    echo $strings[$i];
  }
}
```

Btw I totally did't get what the $percent means..

Comment: Why `if(cond) { continue; }` when you can do `if (!cond)`. Also you only cater for exact matches which is not what is asked for.

Comment: @madxpol $percent is the percentage of similarity which is generated by php's similar_text() function.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `array_filter()` (assumes >= 5.3):

```
$strings = array('software', 'software', 'game', 'antivirus');

$filtered = array_filter($strings, function($curr) {

    static $prev; 

    similar_text($prev, $curr, $percent);
    $prev = $curr;   

    if ($percent < 83) {
        return $curr;
    }        
});

print_r($filtered);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => software
    [2] => game
    [3] => antivirus
)
```

Hope this helps. Actually, I never knew about `similar_text()` until now. Pretty interesting function. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Darragh. Leigh's script worked fine for me. But I will try yours also. If this works, I will test and use the fastest one.

Comment: ha. yes, I just saw Leigh's was marked as answered when I posted! actually, some of the array_* functions are slow enough so I'd bet his will be faster.